# Find $n$ such that $\int_1^n \lfloor{x}\rfloor\lfloor{\sqrt x}\rfloor dx>60$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $$\int_1^n \lfloor{x}\rfloor\lfloor{\sqrt x}\rfloor dx>60$$

where $\lfloor.\rfloor$ is the GIF. I couldn't find any decent method rather than explicitly evaluating it to a few terms by brute force.

Is there a better method out?

Comment: It's not very relevant for the question at hand, but with some work the integral can be evaluated in closed form $$\frac{1}{20}\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor\left(-2\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^4-5\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^3+5\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor+10n^2-10n+2\right)$$

Answer (score 6):

The function $f(x):=\lfloor x\rfloor\cdot\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor$ satisfies $$f(x)=\left\{\eqalign{\lfloor x\rfloor\qquad&(1\leq x<4)\cr 2\lfloor x\rfloor\qquad&(4\leq x<9)\ .\cr}\right.$$
It follows that
$$\int_1^8 f(x)\>dx=1+2+3+8+10+12+14=50\>, $$
and $\int_1^9f(x)\>dx=50+\int_8^9f(x)\>dx=66$.
The answer to your question therefore is $9$.

(Remark: If you had written $6382$ instead of $60$ I would have  set up a general scheme $\ldots$)

Comment: (+1) This was the method by which I solved it... anyways thanks ;-)!!

Comment: Please go ahead and write the general scheme. It many help future readers!